# I just installed PHP5.4 but my localhost is serving PHP5.3

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I just installed PHP 5.4.19 on my os X 10.6.8 Mac using homebrew. I was previously using PHP 5.3.26 probably installed with MacPorts.

If I type php -v in terminal, I get PHP 5.4.19.  If I load a phpinfo() file through my localhost I get PHP 5.3.26.  How do instruct Apache to load my new installation of PHP?

If I run `php --ini`, I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
```

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file has this setting:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
#LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so
```

I am trying to avoid going back to MAMP...

Comment: I had the same issue with mac ports. Try and comment out the line LoadModule php5_module in httpd.conf, then restart Apache. Because 5.3 was already loaded, 5.4 was being skipped as the default version. Here's a post on another board http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/279465-migrating-php-5326-to-54-on-osx-106-using-macports/

Comment: @rwhite35 Thanks, you've put me on to something, but this doesn't work.